# GCC ld Bootloader linking for Cortex M3/M4

Tags: c, gcc, linker, bootloader, cortex-m

I can't find info on what I am trying to achieve. I am using ARM GCC toolchain to develop firmware for a Cortex M4 microcontroller. One of the functions of this firmware is a bootloader which resides in the first addresses of the flash that will check if flashing is needed/possible and then flash the rest of the memory.

For this to work I made sure the bootloader functions are all contained in a section so there will never be a call to the firmware side of the flash. The problem is, I have some functions in the bootloader that I would like to use from firmware. This works very well right now in development as I am compiling and linking everything each time, but I am afraid that in the future gcc/ld will change the layout of the bootloader, making the calls from firmware go to different addresses and breaking old ulpdated systems.

Specifically, I have:

```
.pretext : AT(ORIGIN(FLASH_1_uncached))
{
    KEEP(*(.false.vector));
    *(.Xmc4200.falsepostreset);
    *aes*.o (.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.* .rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*);
    *crc32*.o (.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.* .rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*);
    *bootloader.o (.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.* .rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*);
    *BootCLK*.o (.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.* .rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*);
    *BootIO001*.o (.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.* .rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*);
    *BootIO004*.o (.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.* .rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*);
    *BootRESET001*.o (.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.* .rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*);
    *BootSPI001*.o (.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.* .rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*);
    *bslld*.o (.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.* .rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*);
    __pretext_end = .;
} > FLASH_1_cached

.text ABSOLUTE(0x08008000): AT(0x0C008000)
{
    sText = .;
    *(.Xmc4200.reset);
    KEEP(*(.version));
    *(.Xmc4200.postreset);
    *(.XmcStartup);
    *(EXCLUDE_FILE (*boot_ram.o *FLASH002*.o *aes*.o *bootloader.o *BootCLK*.o *BootIO001*.o *BootIO004*.o *BootRESET001*.o *BootSPI001*.o *bslld*.o *crc32*.o) .text);
    *(EXCLUDE_FILE (*boot_ram.o *FLASH002*.o *aes*.o *bootloader.o *BootCLK*.o *BootIO001*.o *BootIO004*.o *BootRESET001*.o *BootSPI001*.o *bslld*.o *crc32*.o) .text.*);
    *(EXCLUDE_FILE (*boot_ram.o *FLASH002*.o *aes*.o *bootloader.o *BootCLK*.o *BootIO001*.o *BootIO004*.o *BootRESET001*.o *BootSPI001*.o *bslld*.o *crc32*.o) .gnu.linkonce.t.*);
...
```

Notice the following:

- There are some Boot* object files that are mainkly replicas of firmware code that I need in the bootloader with a different naming scheme so there won't be any collisions.
- I have aes and crc up there, as well as some constants that I use from the firmware side
- I haven't included other sections of the linker script related to bootloader part in RAM as it works and I think are not relevant to the question.

What I would like to achieve is, basically, to ensure the bootloader will remain exactly the same address-wise for each symbol in the future so new firmwares will always use those addresses.

I think just using always the same .o files for the bootloader does not ensure anything as the linker may optimize or do something different if in the future another gcc version is used, am I right?

Also, there is no option to just put each symbol on the linker script, or at least, I can't find it. Functions is relatively easy because I compile with -ffunction-sections, but what about other symbols like constants and variables? Is the solution to mask everything under functions and put them ordered in the linker script? Will that work? Is there any other typical solution for this case that I am missing?

Comment: I feel there are a lot of questions at once.

Comment: The `.Xmc4200.reset` sections contains the interrupt vector table, doesn't it? Why don't you extend this table with pointers of your functions? The compiler won't optimize that the linker doesn't it anyway.

Comment: Sorry about the questions, just trying to write down everything that may be useful. That would be an option, yes, but this requires gateway functions or at least function pointer definitions for each of those functions. If there is no other option it's ok, but simpler is better.

Comment: The suggestion of using a table with function pointers is, IMHO, the "right" way to solve this problem. Would you rather make a bunch of function pointer definitions, or monkey with the linker script like crazy? Should you ever want to switch to another (non-gcc-based) toolchain, you'll have the rewrite the linker script from scratch, whereas a function pointer table is 100% portable.

Comment: Is that or mantain two separate copies of the shared code so there will be no crossing between bootloader and firmware, is that it? I will give the table pointer a try, then. Thanks